# React Native Stack Navigation Header Appeared White

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to use Stack Navigator in React Native and using Header in `navigationOptions`.
On android it's working fine. But on IOS Header appeared white before navigate to another screen. Is there any solutions for this problem ? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do in my code. [Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headerstyle)

```
    <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: 'black',
            },
            
        }}
    >
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: I don't want it to appeared in any color. i just want the header disappeared or  appeared in the same Header not change to white.